# iPhone - Can I look at the directory file

Tags: iphone

Once I connect my iPhone to my computer, is there anyway I can look at the directory structure on the phone?
Would it work like a USB device for example and let me copy files without using iTunes but just drag and drop through the Finder on a Mac?

Thanks,
Tee

Comment: Off topic, and no you can't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no. The iPhone filesystem is not accessible from the computer when you connect it via USB in the way that previous generations of iPods and other MP3 players are.

Of course, this may change in the future. If you look at the publicly available information on the iPad you will see there is a way to exchange files between the host computer and the device. However it seems very unlikely that you will ever be able to get full access to the filesystem (at least without jailbreaking).